(Co)limit as Kan extension. Does it need to be pointwise?
$\def\C{\mathsf{C}}
\def\J{\mathsf{J}}
\def\colim{\operatorname{colim}}$Given a small category $\J$, denote $\J^\triangleright$ (resp., $\J^\triangleleft$) to the category $\J$ with a freely-adjoined terminal (resp., initial) object. Write $\iota:\J\to\J^\triangleright$ for obvious inclusion. Let $\C$ be a category, and denote $\operatorname{res}:\C^{\J^\triangleright} \rightarrow \C^\J$ to precomposition by $\iota$.
My question is:

(Q). Are there examples of categories $\C$ and $\J$ so that not all colimits of shape $\J$ exists in $\C$, but $\operatorname{res}$ nevertheless has a left adjoint?

(Thanks to FShrike and Naïm Favier for the kind discussion to distill my actual concern; the statement of (Q) is FShrike's.)
I will give now context of where this question came from. The definition of pointwise Kan extension can be read e.g. here. In [Riehl, Sect. 6.3], we find:

Proposition 6.3.10. A category $\C$ admits all colimits of diagrams indexed by a small category $\J$ if and only if the restriction functor $\C^{\J^\triangleright} \rightarrow \C^\J$ admits a left adjoint, defined by pointwise left Kan extension:
$$
\C^{\J^\triangleright}
\underset{\text{res}}
{
   \stackrel{\colim}
   {
   \underset{\longrightarrow}{\stackrel{\longleftarrow}{\scriptsize\perp}}
   }
}
\C^\J
$$
Dually, $\C$ admits all $\J$-indexed limits if and only if the restriction functor $\C^{\J^\triangleleft} \rightarrow \C^\J$ admits a right adjoint, defined by pointwise right Kan extension:
$$
\C^{\J^\triangleleft}
\underset{\lim}
{
   \stackrel{\text{res}}
   {
   \underset{\longleftarrow}{\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\scriptsize\perp}}
   }
}
\C^\J
$$

I was a little confused while interpreting the statement the way it is phrased. Does the mere existence of a left adjoint to the restriction functor $\C^{\J^\triangleright} \rightarrow \C^\J$ guarantee the existence of pointwise left Kan extensions? The existence of such an adjoint is equivalent to the existence of $\operatorname{Lan}_\iota F$ for every $F:\J\to\C$ [Riehl, Proposition 6.1.5]. But can we deduce $\operatorname{Lan}_\iota F$ is always pointwise in this case?
If it happens that there are counterexamples, I guess a way to phrase the first part of Proposition 6.3.10 that doesn't get me into misunderstandings is:

Let $\J$ be a small category. Write $\iota:\J\hookrightarrow\J^\triangleright$ for the canonical inclusion. A category $\C$ admits all colimits of diagrams indexed by $\J$ if and only for all functors $F:\J\to\C$, $\operatorname{Lan}_\iota F$ exists and is pointwise. Moreover, in such a case, the left Kan extension functor $\operatorname{Lan}_\iota:\C^\J \rightarrow \C^{\J^\triangleright}$ is identified with the colimit functor.

(The fact that $\operatorname{Lan}_\iota:\C^\J \rightarrow \C^{\J^\triangleright}$ is left adjoint to restriction is [Riehl, Proposition 6.1.5].)

References
[Riehl] E. Riehl, Category Theory in Context

$\mathrm{Lan}\mathrm{res} F$ is ill-typed: $F$ and $\mathrm{res}$ do not have the same domain. Do you mean $\mathrm{Lan}\iota F$?

@NaïmFavier Yes, thanks. I just edited it.

In "freely-adjoined terminal (resp., final) object", "terminal" and "final" mean the same thing. Did you mean to say "initial" in place of one of those synonyms (i.e., "freely-adjoined terminal (resp., initial) object" or "freely-adjoined initial (resp., final) object")?

@GeoffreyTrang Thanks for the erratum. I just edited the post.

It does need to be pointwise.
In fact, the right Kan extension exists iff. the $\mathsf{J}$-indexed limits exist iff. the extension is pointwise.
Assume $R=\mathrm{Ran}_\iota$ exists. Fix any diagram $F$ of shape $\mathsf{J}$ in $\mathsf{C}$. Consider an object $\varsigma$ and the constant diagram $\Delta\varsigma:\mathsf{J}^{\unlhd}\to\mathsf{C}$. You can see that natural transformations $\Delta\varsigma\to RF$ are exactly determined by a choice of map $\varsigma\to RF(\star)$, if $\star$ is the adjoined initial object. This determination is also natural. It follows: $$\mathsf{C}(\varsigma,RF(\star))\cong\mathsf{C}^{\mathsf{J}^{\unlhd}}(\Delta\varsigma,RF)\cong\mathsf{C}^{\mathsf{J}}(\Delta\varsigma,F)\cong\mathrm{Cone}(\varsigma,F)$$Naturally in both variables. Then $F\mapsto RF(\star)$ is a choice of limit functor; all limits of shape $\mathsf{J}$ exist.

Old version of the post (answering a different question):
I claim $\mathsf{C}$ has $\mathsf{J}$-indexed limits if and only if $(1)$ $\mathrm{res}$'s right adjoint, $\mathrm{Ran}_{\iota}$, exists and $(2)$ the Kan extension is a pointwise one. Note this isn't a priori immediate since the "every extension is pointwise" theorem requires limits of mildly arbitrary shape, not just fixed shape $\mathsf{J}$.
But if the limits of shape $\mathsf{J}$ exist then we know how to define the right adjoint by hand and we can manually check it is pointwise: the only interesting thing happens at the initial object, and you can see $\mathsf{C}(\varsigma,\mathrm{Ran}_\iota F)\cong\mathrm{Ran}_\iota\mathsf{C}(\varsigma,F)$ just by the same basic manual construction and the fact $\mathsf{C}(\varsigma,\varprojlim F)\cong\varprojlim\mathsf{C}(\varsigma,F)$.
In the converse direction, we want to show what morally should be true: that $\mathrm{Ran}_\iota F(\star)$ would be a limit for $F$, so all $\mathsf{J}$-indexed limits would exist. I say that we can deduce this if we assume a pointwise Kan extension. For then we know $\mathrm{Ran}_\iota F(\star)\cong\varprojlim((\star|\iota)\to\mathsf{J}\to\mathsf{C})$, but the map $(\star|\iota)\to\mathsf{J}$ is an isomorphism because $\star$ is initial (think about it) so $\mathsf{Ran}_\iota F(\star)\cong\varprojlim F$; in particular, $\varprojlim F$ exists.

Thanks! I came to realize what you explained as well. However, what I was actually interested in is what you discuss in your first paragraph. Maybe I should have stressed it more in my question.

@ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo I thought you were asking if you had interpreted Riehl’s statement correctly (and I confirmed this by saying yes,  there is a pointwise extension iff. the limits exist)

Accordingly the question could rephrased as follows: are there examples of categories $\mathsf{C}$ and $\mathsf{J}$ so that not all limits of shape $\mathsf{J}$ exists in $\mathsf{C}$, but $\mathrm{res}$ nevertheless has a right adjoint?

@ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo It is true! It’s always pointwise. Edited my answer

Cool! Thanks a bunch! More generally, for a functor $G:\mathsf{J}^\triangleleft\to\mathsf{C}$, natural transformations $\Delta\varsigma\Rightarrow G$ bijectively correspond to morphisms $\varsigma\to G(\star)$, naturally in $\varsigma$ and $G$.

There are two levels at play here:

For every functor $F : \mathsf{J}\to\mathsf{C}$, we define $\mathrm{colim}\ F : \mathsf{J}^\triangleright \to \mathsf{C}$ as the left Kan extension $\mathrm{Lan}_\iota\ F$ and prove that this Kan extension is pointwise (proposition 6.3.10).
This construction assembles into a functor $\mathrm{colim} : \mathsf{C}^\mathsf{J} \to \mathsf{C}^{\mathsf{J}^\triangleright}$ which is left adjoint to the precomposition functor $\mathrm{res} = - \circ \iota : \mathsf{C}^{\mathsf{J}^\triangleright} \to \mathsf{C}^\mathsf{J}$, making this a global Kan extension functor. Moreover, left adjoints are absolute right Kan extensions along the identity (see here), so we also have $\mathrm{colim} = \mathrm{Ran}_\mathrm{res}\ \mathrm{Id}_{\mathsf{C}^{\mathsf{J}^\triangleright}}$ and this extension is absolute, hence pointwise.

Does this answer your question?

Which direction of the equivalence are you arguing? Also, is it $\operatorname{Ran}\iota$ or $\operatorname{Ran}\text{res}$?

What equivalence do you mean? I'm just trying to clarify things. It is $\mathrm{Ran}_\mathrm{res}$ in the second level.

I mean: what are your hypotheses? Are you always assuming that $\mathsf{C}$ is cocomplete?

Oh, yeah, that direction.

I see. My trouble is with the other direction: It is exactly what FShrike writes in the first paragraph of their answer.
